# delete post php source

Tags: php, post, comments

I need help. I have created posting system. i need now to create delete system. i need just to put system that will delete specefic that post that somebody need to delete. here is my posting system.

```
if(empty($_POST) === false){
 $status_data = array(
   'status' => $_POST['status'],
   'status_poster' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
   'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
   );
   update_status($id, $status_data, $user_id);
  }  
   if($profile_data['user_id']){

     ?>
        <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="field">
    <label for="Status" style="color: #7f7f7f; font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif;"></label>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="status"placeholder="say something" id="status_area" ></textarea>
    <div id="button">
    <input name="user_status" type="submit" value="Post">
    </div>
    </div>
       </form>
       </div>
       <div id="status">
        <?php
    if($_Get['delete']){
   $id = $_GET['delete'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM status WHERE id='$id'";
    $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    echo"<meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content =' 0;url=index.php'>";
    }
      ?>
     <?php
    }
    if(user_exists($username) === true){
$user_id         = user_id_from_username($username);
$profile_data    = user_data($user_id, 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_id');

    $find_post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY date DESC");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_post)){
$post_id = $rows['id'];
$first_name = $profile_data['first_name'];
$last_name = $profile_data['last_name'];
$username = $profile_data['username'];
$user = $user_data['user_id'];
$data = $rows['date'];
$post_name = $rows['status_poster'];
$post = $rows['status'];
    if( $user_id === $post_name){
    ?>

    <div class='holder'>
   <div class='holder_half'>
   <?php
echo '<div id="picture">
<img src="', $profile_data['profile_picture'], '" alt="', $profile_data['first_name'],'\'s Profile image">';
echo "
</div>
<div class='ten'>
<div id='statusname'><a href='#'>$first_name $last_name</a></div>
<div class='date_time'>posted at $data</div>
<span class='span' data-ft='{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}'>
<div id='statustext'>$post</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<textarea rows='4' cols='50' id='comment' name='comment' placeholder='' id='status_area' ></textarea>
</div>
";
        }
    }
 }
   }
   ?>   
   </div>
    </div>if(empty($_POST) === false){
$status_data = array(
'status' => $_POST['status'],
'status_poster' => $_SESSION['user_id'],
'date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
);
update_status($id, $status_data, $user_id);
    }
   if($profile_data['user_id']){
      ?>
     <form action="" method="post">
<div class="field">
    <label for="Status" style="color: #7f7f7f; font-family: Cambria, Hoefler Text, Liberation Serif, Times, Times New Roman, serif;"></label>
    <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="status"placeholder="say something" id="status_area" ></textarea>
    <div id="button">
    <input name="user_status" type="submit" value="Post">
    </div>
 </div>
    </form>
   </div>
   <div id="status">
   <?php
   if($_Get['delete']){
$id = $_GET['delete'];
$sql = "DELETE FROM status WHERE id='$id'";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo"<meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content =' 0;url=index.php'>";
   }
    ?>
      <?php
        }
   if(user_exists($username) === true){
$user_id         = user_id_from_username($username);
$profile_data    = user_data($user_id, 'first_name', 'last_name', 'user_id');

    $find_post = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM status ORDER BY date DESC");
    while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($find_post)){
$post_id = $rows['id'];
$first_name = $profile_data['first_name'];
$last_name = $profile_data['last_name'];
$username = $profile_data['username'];
$user = $user_data['user_id'];
$data = $rows['date'];
$post_name = $rows['status_poster'];
$post = $rows['status'];
    if( $user_id === $post_name){
    ?>
     <div class='holder'>
     <div class='holder_half'>
      <?php
echo '<div id="picture">
<img src="', $profile_data['profile_picture'], '" alt="', $profile_data['first_name'],'\'s Profile image">';
echo "
</div>
<div class='ten'>
<div id='statusname'><a href=''>$first_name $last_name</a></div>
<div class='date_time'>posted at $data</div>
<span class='span' data-ft='{&quot;tn&quot;:&quot;K&quot;}'>
<div id='statustext'>$post</div>
</span>
</div>
</div>
<textarea rows='4' cols='50' id='comment' name='comment' placeholder='' id='status_area' ></textarea>
</div>
  ";
        }
    }
}
      }
    ?>  
     </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I love those curly braces down there, look like some arcade videogame

Comment: @DamienPirsy Yea. i like it to.

Comment: `$_Get['delete']` to `$_GET['delete']`

Comment: @FerozAkbar i have changed it to $_GET['delete'] but not worked.

Comment: how are you calling delete operation?

Comment: are you getting any errors back?

Comment: i haven't created it now. i'm searching for it

Comment: i'm asking how are you testing the delete operaiton?

Comment: @Magna i haven't create delete option. there is just for now if it is true or not. i will create after answers. :)

Comment: i'am testing in another php file.    if($_POST){
 $sql = "DELETE FROM status WHERE id='$id'";
 $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 echo"<meta http-equiv = 'refresh' content =' 0;url=index.php'>";
          }

Comment: Ok just to be clear what is the problem then? is the delete not working?

Comment: @Magna i need just create a delete system that will delete just that post, that i need. not other posts. i haven't create any delete system. it is 1 time. i don't now how to do it.

Comment: Ok but what about the delete query you have up there? isn't that working?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 delete queries in the code but you are asking how to create one..here is mysqli prepared statements version(prevents sql injection)..

```
$database = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'database_name');
//you select like this
$stmt  = $database->prepare("select * from status order by date desc");
$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();

while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc()){

  //the rows here
  }
```

delete... I am not sure if you are either doing the delete on separate page, meaning you click on the post and it takes you to second page where you see the delete button, or [on the same page] deleting the posts by checking a checkbox for each post. if you are doing the first method the below code will delete it but first you need to pass the id to second page via url like click

```
$id = $_GET['id']

$stmt = $database->prepare("DELETE from status where id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('i', $id);//you could put 's' if the id contains other than numbers
$stmt->execute();
```

this will delete posts where the id matches.